# Last item in React native flat list goes beyond screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-stylesheet

I have a flatlist with some styles on the outer containers as follows.

```
<View style={containerStyle}>
 // more jsx components come here
  <View style={resultContainerStyle}>
    <FlatList
      data={results}
      keyExtractor={(item) => (item.id && item.id.toString())}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
        <ListItem
          item={item}
          selectItem={selectItem}
        />
      )}
    />
  </View>
</View>
```

The issue is that the last values of the list go beyond the view of the screen and there is no way to view it unless a fixed height is put on the parent container. Is it possible to do this without a fixed height.

[image: image-of-problem]

Comment: Could you please update with both the styles?

Comment: parent of FlatsList should have "flex:1" and try to add style to FlatList with "flex:1"

Comment: can you add your styles to description as well?

Answer (score 1):

A `SafeAreaView` can be used to limit the view to the "safe" areas of the screen(avoiding the notch and curved bottom. Checkout the following example

```
<SafeAreaView style={containerStyle}>
 // more jsx components come here
  <View style={resultContainerStyle}>
    <FlatList
      data={results}
      keyExtractor={(item) => (item.id && item.id.toString())}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
        <ListItem
          item={item}
          selectItem={selectItem}
        />
      )}
    />
  </View>
</SafeAreaView>
```

more examples can be found at the [react native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/safeareaview).

Comment: This issue isn't about the safe area. Even though i swap it in a safe area it keeps extending beyond the screen

Comment: It isn't entirely clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Should the items outside area be hidden? Does it fail to register clicks?